# How wait for TWebBrowser is loaded in FOR ... TO ... DO?

Tags: delphi

I have a this code:

```
    for i:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
       begin
           while WebBrowser1.Busy do Application.ProcessMessages;
           WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Links.item(cat[i]).click;
           subcatList;
       end;
```

but WebBrowser1 run several times in spite of the expectations of the procedure. How do I start WebBrowser1 not in the background or what is the solution?

Comment: Could you elaborate what *WebBrowser1 run several times* ? And what procedure ? Did you mean some event or where is the code you've posted placed ? Please take the time to update your question since it's unaswerable at this time.

Comment: I have a some link on loaded page in WebBrowser and need click each in FOR cycle and wait until complete processing 1st link. In Memo1.Lines i have some link. subcatlist thiы is procedure like this code.Оn the site several categories of investments, I collect all attachments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement 3 events of TWebBrowser, BeforeNavigate2, DocumentComplete and NavigateComplete2

```
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    private
      CurDispatch: IDispatch; 
      FDocLoaded: Boolean;    
    ....


    procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
      const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
      var Cancel: WordBool);
    begin
      CurDispatch := nil;
      FDocLoaded := False;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
      const URL: OleVariant);
    begin
      if (pDisp = CurDispatch) then  
      begin
        FDocLoaded := True;
        CurDispatch := nil;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
      const URL: OleVariant);
    begin
      if CurDispatch = nil then
        CurDispatch := pDisp;
    end;
```

And now you can use FDocLoaded variable to know if the page is loaded into the WebBrowser

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.stackoverflow.com');
    repeat Application.ProcessMessage until FDocLoaded;
```

Regards

Comment: Application.ProcessMessage or Application.ProcessMessages?

Comment: @TLama this solutions function with a page with frames?

Comment: Note that the `OnDocumentComplete` event handler is executed only when the `TWebBrowser` control is displayed (For example, if it is placed inside an inactive tab, it will be executed only at the tab's activation)