# Delphi WebBrowsing

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I want to automate the following process:
I log in to a website.
On the search page, enter the information I want to search and click on the search button.
The click loads my result.
From the resulting page, I select the option to preview the pdf file, and click the button.
This click uploads my pdf file.

If I split these commands into buttons, and I press it one by one everything is working fine, but when I want to execute all the commands in a row I get the an error. (I think the error is because WebBrowser does not load everything.) Please help.

```
procedure TMainForm.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
var doc :IHTMLDocument2;
    FileStream: TFileStream;
    StreamAdapter: IStream;
    PersistStreamInit: IPersistStreamInit;
    i, a, b : integer;
    sir: string;
    MergiInainte:boolean;'

begin
    MergiInainte:=false;
    WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/externallogin.aspx');'

    repeat
      if ((WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE) and (WebBrowser1.Busy = false)) then
        MergiInainte:=true;
    until MergiInainte;'   // This repeat is not working. Dont know why?

    //After webBrowser is fully loaded, the next code has to be run
    doc := WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2;
    WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtNume','user');
    WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtPwd','psswd');
    WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('tibAutentification').click;'

    //after the above code is fully executat, next code is in line
    WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/Pages/SearchTitle.aspx');

    //after the above code is executed, next i need to complete form element with what the nexd data
    doc := WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2;
    WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('chkTitleNo').click;
    WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtTitleNo','28972');   //nr titlu de proprietate
    WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('tibSearch').click;

    WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('fdgMain:_ctl3:imbView').click;

    WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('tibViewPDF').click;  
end;


// But i'm getting error:  Access violation....read of adress 0000000.'

procedure TForm1.WebFormSetFieldValue(const document: IHTMLDocument2; const formNumber: integer; const fieldName, newValue: string) ;
var form : IHTMLFormElement;
    field: IHTMLElement;
begin
  form := WebFormGet(formNumber, WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2) ;
  field := form.Item(fieldName,'') as IHTMLElement;
  if field = nil then Exit;
  if field.tagName = 'INPUT' then (field as IHTMLInputElement).value := newValue;
  if field.tagName = 'SELECT' then (field as IHTMLSelectElement).value := newValue;
  if field.tagName = 'TEXTAREA' then (field as IHTMLTextAreaElement).value := newValue;
end;
```

Comment: We readers cannot see your screen.  On which **exact** line do your get the AV?  Please add this info to your q.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890332/12763954) (although I'm not sure why he handles 3 events and not just DocumentComplete).

Answer (score 2):

Submitting a web form is a navigation, so you have to wait on the `ReadyState` and `Busy` properties again after calling `tibAutentification.click` (asuming that is the webform's submit button).  Same with the 2nd `Navigate()` call.  Also, you need to pump the calling thread's message queue while waiting for the browser to be ready so that it can actually process its state changes correctly.

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3: IHTMLDocument3;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  StreamAdapter: IStream;
  PersistStreamInit: IPersistStreamInit;
  i, a, b : integer;
  sir: string;

  procedure WaitForReady;
  begin
    while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/externallogin.aspx');

  WaitForReady;
  doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
  WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtNume','user');
  WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtPwd','psswd');
  doc3.GetElementByID('tibAutentification').click;

  WaitForReady;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/Pages/SearchTitle.aspx');

  WaitForReady;
  doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
  doc3.GetElementByID('chkTitleNo').click;
  WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtTitleNo','28972');   //nr titlu de proprietate
  doc3.GetElementByID('tibSearch').click;

  WaitForReady; // ?
  doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
  doc3.GetElementByID('fdgMain:_ctl3:imbView').click;

  WaitForReady; // ?
  doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
  doc3.GetElementByID('tibViewPDF').click;  
end;

procedure TForm1.WebFormSetFieldValue(const document: IHTMLDocument2;
  const formNumber: integer; const fieldName, newValue: string);
var
  form : IHTMLFormElement;
  field: IHTMLElement;
begin
  if document = nil then Exit;
  form := WebFormGet(formNumber, document);
  if form = nil then Exit;
  field := form.Item(fieldName,'') as IHTMLElement;
  if field = nil then Exit;
  if field.tagName = 'INPUT' then
    (field as IHTMLInputElement).value := newValue
  else if field.tagName = 'SELECT' then
    (field as IHTMLSelectElement).value := newValue
  else if field.tagName = 'TEXTAREA' then
    (field as IHTMLTextAreaElement).value := newValue;
end;
```

Because of reentry issues related to pumping the message queue manually, serializing this code is not a good idea, you should use the browser's `OnDocumentComplete` event instead, let the VCL handle the message processing for you, eg (may require some tweaking):

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/externallogin.aspx');
  WebBrowser1.Tag := 1;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const Disp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  doc3: IHTMLDocument3;
begin
  case WebBrowser1.Tag of
    1: begin
      doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
      WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtNume','user');
      WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtPwd','psswd');
      doc3.GetElementByID('tibAutentification').click;
      WebBrowser1.Tag := 2;
    end;

    2: begin
      WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://website/Pages/SearchTitle.aspx');
      WebBrowser1.Tag := 3;
    end;

    3: begin
      doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
      doc3.GetElementByID('chkTitleNo').click;
      WebFormSetFieldValue(doc,0,'txtTitleNo','28972');   //nr titlu de proprietate
      doc3.GetElementByID('tibSearch').click;
      WebBrowser1.Tag := 4;
    end;

    4: begin
      doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
      doc3.GetElementByID('fdgMain:_ctl3:imbView').click;
      WebBrowser1.Tag := 5;
    end;

    5: begin
      doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      doc3 := doc as IHTMLDocument3;
      doc3.GetElementByID('tibViewPDF').click;
      WebBrowser1.Tag := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Indeed OnDocumentComplete, is the correct choice, watch out though, it is fired multiple times if the webpage has frames (once per frame).

Comment: @whosrdaddy that is easy to differentiate, using the `Disp` parameter to see if the completed document belongs to a frame document or the top level document.

Comment: Remy, In know, doing these things for a loong time, just wanted to warn future readers of this culprit :)

Comment: WaitForReady; --> is not working. OnDocumentComplete --> is working fine. Thank you. Sometime WebBrowser is showing a MessageBox with ok button, any idea how to capture/ close it automaticaly.